# How do I protect a directory in iis?

Tags: apache, iis, azure-web-roles

In apache I do:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=255.111.222.111
RewriteRule . / [L]
</IfModule>
```

How do I do so in iis azure web?

Answer (score 0):

Please define "protect a directory in iis?"

ASP.NET website's Web.config is part of an inheritance chain. Your website's subfolders can have Web.config to override settings just for these folders.

Read more on eb.config inherance [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx).

To block all access to any file extension within the a specificdirectory (or subdirectories), simply add a new web.config. N

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Access is blocked by mapping these any file to the HttpNotFoundHandler, so that a 404 error is returned when trying to access a view directly.